# Selective change to upper case in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In the following lines of text is it possible to only change the text before the first comma to upper case?
I need to be able to do this for over 360,000 lines.

```
1 Mile Bore WA,Bore,,-26.88000,117.10000

1 Mile Bore WA,Bore,,-23.48000,116.09000

1 Mile Bore WA,Bore,,-26.04000,116.97000

1 Mile Bore WA,Bore,,-27.05000,115.88000

1 Mile Bore WA,Bore,,-17.25000,127.46000

1 Mile Bore WA,Bore,,-17.79000,127.69000

1 Mile Creek WA,Stream,,-20.86000,119.73000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I have used some regex:

1. Press Ctrl+H.
2. Copy-paste `^(.+?\,)(.*)` in find.
3. Copy-paste `\U$1\E$2` in replace.
4. Start replacing.

Output of your strings:

```
1 MILE BORE WA,Bore,,-26.88000,117.10000

1 MILE BORE WA,Bore,,-23.48000,116.09000

1 MILE BORE WA,Bore,,-26.04000,116.97000

1 MILE BORE WA,Bore,,-27.05000,115.88000

1 MILE BORE WA,Bore,,-17.25000,127.46000

1 MILE BORE WA,Bore,,-17.79000,127.69000

1 MILE CREEK WA,Stream,,-20.86000,119.73000
```

Comment: I know that I change all the text to caps, but I only need the text before the first comma to be all caps.

Comment: Isn't that what it does?

Comment: Firts comma in your example is Before `Bore` and `Stream`

Comment: So as you ca see `Bore` and `Stream` are not uppercase, and the text before them IS uppercase, just as you wanted isn't it?

Comment: Thank you BladeMight, that worked perfectly. you're a champion.

Comment: And vote up please?

Comment: Okay, I'm new here. What do you mean by accept the answer, and what is vote up?

Comment: Not enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Here on top left of my answer there are ^ icon click it to vote up if you think that this answer was helpful, just down to it there are ✓(checkmark) icon click it to accept answer as correct.